# How to show the scrollbar on UITableView with indexes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with indexes (sectionIndexTitlesForTableView) and I want to show the scrollbar when the user scrolls this table. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

Is that [self.tableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];  ? But the default value of showsHorizontalScrollIndicator is YES;

Comment: I need a vertical scroll, so I set the  setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES, but it didn't help. I think I need to override the standard behaviour somehow, but I have no ideas how.

Comment: Why not add the tableView on the scrollView? Maybe it's a stupid method!